# Laptop suddenly v slow, fixed by pci=routeirq. Bad PSMouse driver?

Tags: drivers, 18.04

My laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 slowed down til it was unusable, and I saw a few psmouse lost synchronisation messages in dmesg.

Restarting, the laptop booted grub fine, then starting ubuntu was the same dead slow speed as before I could see the screen only doing something when the hard drive light flashed, about every 2s. So I thought it was an interrupt issue, causing the hard drive reads to take ages.
So soon enough, after looking at this page
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingIRQProblems
Part 2 saying to use pci=routeirq in the kernel parameters, it worked! now the laptop runs fine.

Obviously there's an underlying issue here though.

How do I troubleshoot the interrupts and find out what's causing the slowdown please?

Thanks in advance